# how can I convert this string into a list through the command line

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have files that are named like `C1_1_B_(1)IMG1511.jpg` and I want to split them up into a list where i get back as

```
 C1
 1
 B
 (1)
 IMG1511.jpg
```

trying to figure out if i need to do this with `sed` or `awk` or `regex` or even what that would look like i could do it in applescript but I would rather call shell command as it is much faster

**EDIT**

Ok so now its changed a bit and I can figure out how to fix it

example are

```
"P24-M_(1)Lighter_Ray_Logo_Full_Color.jpg" 
"P24_(1)24x36loren.jpg"
```

so _(*) indicates where I want to stop listing so i end up with

```
P24
M
(1)
Lighter_Ray_Logo_Full_Color.jpg
```

and

```
P24
(1)
24x36loren.jpg
```

Comment: For clarification, will the file names always have 3 underscores and one pair of parenthesis?

Comment: it could have more underscores but the parens will always be follwed by some text and dot extension thanks for asking about that

Comment: If it was just the underscores, `IFS=_ set ...` would be a good solution. For the parenthesis, this is not suitable, so `echo | sed` is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Translate `_` to new lines:

```
echo "C1_1_B_(1)IMG1511.jpg" | tr '_' '\n'
```

Output:

```
C1
1
B
(1)IMG1511.jpg
```

Although, it looks like you want to split on `)` as well. No can do with `tr`, but...

```
echo "C1_1_B_(1)IMG1511.jpg" | tr '_' '\n' | sed -e 's/)/)\
/'
```

There's a linefeed *inside* the replacement string, which is needed for Mac. On other *nix OS's, a simple escape works:

```
echo "C1_1_B_(1)IMG1511.jpg" | tr '_' '\n' | sed -e 's/)/)\n/'
```

Output:

```
C1
1
B
(1)
IMG1511.jpg
```

Comment: @Alfred Fazio: may as well take it further (less)... `sed 's/)/)_/;s/_/\n/g'` ... (using only one utility)

Comment: @fered when I use just sed I get C1n1nBn(1)nIMG1511.jpg so there are no returns why is in not making the new lines and just putting n there

Comment: @mcgrailm. I have no real idea why it would be doing that. Maybe you are using a different *sed* (mine is GNU 4.2.1). Try it this way, `sed -e 's/)/)_/' -e 's/_/\n/g'` .. If you have a differnt sed, try using `\\n` ????

Comment: I got it echo "P24-M_(1)Lighter_Ray_Logo_Full_Color.jpg" | tr '-' '\n' | sed -e 's/_(/\n(/' | sed -e 's/)/)\n/'

Answer (score 1):

Would this do?

```
 <<<"C1_1_B_(1)IMG1511.jpg" sed -r 'y/_/\n/;s/\([^)]*\)/&\n/g;'
```

Comment: `s/([^)]\*)/&\n/g;` caters for left paren, followed by anything but a right paren or nothing, followed by a right paren.

Comment: ... but when I run it, it keeps `(1)IMG1511.jpg` all on the same line. The OP wants `(1)` and `IMG1511.jpg` on different lines... The `\*` is escaping `*` and that causes a not-matched situation... Maybe we are using diffferent versions of `sed` ... I'm using: *GNU sed version 4.2.1*

Comment: Your right fered - I amended it from sed -r option (which I've now reverted to) forgetting that '()' didn't need quoting. The above version should work.

Comment: @fered this is my attempt to handle your test data `sed -r 's/([^_])(\([^)]*\))/\1_\2/g;y/_/\n/;s/\([^)]*\)/&\n/g;:a;s/\(([^)\n]*)\n/(\1_/g;ta'`

Comment: I'll haven't looked at it fully, because it throws an error (copied and pasted from above).. It took me a while to figure out why.. I tracked it down to the fact that (on this web page, at least) it has 2 embedded Zero-Width characters: [Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH JOINER' (U+200D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm) and [Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER' (U+200C)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm)... They are in a place which is syntactically invalid, just before the `;ta`.. :(

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not sed/awk, but here's something that would work in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<STDIN>) {
  my($line) = $_;
  chomp($line);

  my @values = split(/_|(\(\d+\))/, $line);

    foreach my $val (@values) {
    if ( $val !~ m/^$/)
    {
        print "$val\n";
    }
  }
}
exit 0;
```

Comment: iKeya thats cool but its hard to put that into applescript i really need something small like one or two lines as I don't want to add the complexity of a required file to this job

Answer (score 0):

If the filename is stored in $P, the following works with zsh:

```
myarr=${(s/_/)$(echo $P | sed 's/)/)_/g')}
```

This creates an actual array.

Answer (score 0):

This handles filenames which contain  `_ ( )` in other places.

```
<<< '
C1_1_B_(1)IMG151).jpg
C1_1_B_(1)IMG_(4444).jpg
C(22)2_1_22_333_B_(144)I_M_G_(_1511).jpg
' sed -nr '# isolate, process and print first section 
             s/^([^(]+)_/\1\n/;h
             s/(.*)\n.*/\1/
             s/([^_]+)_/\1\n/gp;x
           # process the second section 
             s/.*\n(.*)/\1/
             s/([^)]+\))/\1\n/p
           ';exit
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
str="C1_1_B_(1)IMG1511.jpg"
ary=( $(IFS=_; echo $str) )

for ((idx=0; idx < ${#ary[@]}; idx++)); do echo ${ary[$idx]}; done
```

outputs

```
C1
1
B
(1)IMG1511.jpg
```